# CTreeCntrl: SetItemImage cause the redraw of whole item

Tags: mfc

I need to implement something like animated tree images. So I have 4 states of the same icon, for just testing it I have created VS 2010 new project and add just handler for ON_WM_TIMER and in function add (700 msec timer)

```
void CClassView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    HTREEITEM hItem = m_wndClassView.GetRootItem(); 
    HTREEITEM hCurSel = m_wndClassView.GetNextItem(hItem, TVGN_CHILD ); 
    int nImage, nSelImage; 
    m_wndClassView.GetItemImage(hCurSel, nImage,nSelImage);
    int nNewImgae = nImage == 4 ? 1 : nImage+1;
    m_wndClassView.SetItemImage(hCurSel, nNewImgae, nNewImgae);
}
```

So everything is fine my icon became animated and moving ,but sometimes I see that whole tree item redrawing (not only icon image but item image with text). So is there any possibility to fix it?

Comment: You could try disabling redraw with `SetRedraw(FALSE)` until after the call to `SetItemImage` and then invalidating only the image rect, which you will probably need to calculate yourself.

Comment: If I set `SetRedraw(FALSE)` I need after set it `TRUE` it can cause a redraw of whole list control :)